# One-to-many relationship MySQL - get only one many-record

Tags: mysql

I got 2 tables, one of my table looks like this (example):

```
tbl1
-------------
id int PK
name string
```

The other one looks like:

```
tbl2
-------------
type int PK FK (tbl1.id)
langid int PK
content string
```

So what I want: I want to get all rows from tbl1 joined together with results from tbl2. But what I don't want is for every langid add a result to the join. So if tbl1 contains this data:

```
id: 1, name: test1
id: 2, name: test2
```

And tbl2 contains this data:

```
type: 1, langid: 1, content: testcontent
type: 1, langid: 2, content: testcontent2
type: 2, langid: 3, content: testcontent3
```

I want only the following data:

```
tbl1.id: 1, tbl1.name: test1, tbl2.type: 1, tbl2.langid: 1, tbl2.content: testcontent
tbl1.id: 2, tbl1.name: test2, tbl2.type: 2, tbl2.langid: 3, tbl2.content: testcontent3
```

So it has to get one result with the langid that exist. Hopefully I explained it well. I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl1` INNER JOIN `tbl2` ON (`tbl1`.`id` = `tbl2`.`type`) WHERE `tbl2`.`langid` = 1
```

But sometimes langid 1 doesn't exist, and just langid 2 by that header. I need to get the tbl1 row with one result from tbl2.

Comment: ... where 'tbl2'.'langid' = 1 ...   ??

Comment: Yeah forgot that, thanks for noticing.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "But sometimes langid 1 doesn't exist, and just langid 2 by that header. I need to get the tbl1 row with one result from tbl2."   Your code says get the output for the join when table #2, language ID = 1.  If that languageID doesn't exist, you should get a null set as a response.  What output are you getting? Hint:  http://sqlfiddle.com/ is your friend, when trying to ask questions like this.

Comment: I mean sometimes there isn't a tbl2 for a specific type with langid = 1, but there is one with langid = 2 for example. Then it has to get that tbl2 join, else it has to get where langid = 1, if 2 doesn't exist 3 etc. I'll try to build it in SQLfiddle.

Comment: So you just want the first entry upon the join?  What is it that you want?  (Use plain english, don't try to voice it in SQL talk...)

Comment: The SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ea3b. I want to get all data from the first table and just one entry from the second yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original submission (just gets first response...  but that's not what you want...)

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl1` INNER JOIN `tbl2` ON (`tbl1`.`id` = `tbl2`.`type`) WHERE 1 LIMIT 1
```

Update -- I think this is what you want.  This works on the [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ea3b/24)

```
select *
  FROM `tbl1` INNER JOIN `tbl2` 
  ON ( `tbl1`.`id` = `tbl2`.`type`) 
  Group by tbl1.id
```

Response:

```
id  name    type    langid  content
1   test1     1       1    content1
2   test2     2       3    content3
```

Comment: Doesn't work, your edit will just get one result; so also just one result from `tbl1`

Comment: The hardest thing to do here is voice exactly what you want in the simplest terms possible.  I think we all struggle with that.

Comment: Yeah... I'm used to explain everything in code language and I'm Dutch so explaining is even harder for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `LEFT JOIN`, with the condition on the other table in the join condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tbl1` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl2` ON `tbl1`.`id` = `tbl2`.`type`
  AND `tbl2`.`langid` = 1
```

This will give you every row from tbl1 once each, with data from tbl2 only if it exists with langid 1.

Comment: The problem is it should try to get langid = 2 when = 1 returns a NULL and so on.